# qtip with handlebars

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, handlebars.js, qtip

I've looked around a while for this but I couldn't find anything. I'm trying to use a handlebars template in conjunction with a qtip. I guess one approach would be to convert the handlebars template to a string and put it as a value in 'content', but I'm not sure how to convert a handlebars template to a string.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you precisely describe what you want to achieve? and state what you have tried? or at least some pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

So I got this, sorry if the question was unclear, I wasn't sure how to ask it!

```
objectData = {field1 : value, field2: value1}
html = Handlebarstemplates[templateHere](objectData)
$(".tooltip").qtip({
content:{
  text:html
}
  })
```